# Jupyter not opening and going unresponsive

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am having a weird issue with Jupyter where it just won't open certain notebooks or they will take forever to open. I will open a notebook and a new page will open for the existing notebook the page will partially load the Jupyter header but none of the cells will load and it will just sit like that, then eventually I'll get a pop up saying page unresponsive: "wait or exit". If I hit wait it will just continue to sit blank until the next "wait or exit" notifcation comes up. It only does this with certain notebooks. I was just working with this notebook and I had to quit out because it froze and after restarting my computer and anaconda this is what happened. One of the notebooks I was given for school this semester still to this day will not open. The one I was just using eventually opened but I had to let it sit for over a minute. Does anyone have any ideas? These notebooks aren't really large or anything. I have definitely run much larger files.

Thank you
[image]

Comment: when you open Jupiter notebook, usually you will see a command prompt that is open and showing messages(this depends on configuration), do you have that terminal or command prompt and see if you see any errors there? another option(workaround) just to see what is the content of notebook which you are unable to open - is  to try google colab.

Comment: @simpleApp do you mean like opening it through Anaconda? If so I am not having any errors in Anaconda when it opens. But I didn't know I could do that with google colab! Thank you!

Comment: yes , pls. when you click 'launch' you will see a terminal is also getting fired. for Google Colab, try it it's easy and powerful and works almost the same way as a Jupiter notebook.

Comment: @simpleApp its getting stuck with something called "Type setting" and something about "mathjax" do you have any idea what this is. I keep having to restart jupter and anaconda

Comment: what is the version of jupyter?(in anaconda navigator you can see that), also if its older version, you can try to update(in the navigator,r you will see that once you click on the setting icon )  it to the next version or the latest version to see if the problem still persist.